# plot by Tikz as the same figure

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot, angle

[image]

I would like to draw the same as the figure by Tikz

Comment: Hello and welcome to TeX-SE. You probably searched a bit on how to draw with Ti*k*Z, and this drawing is pretty straightforward. Did you try something yet? If not, please do so and come back with questions about how to improve your work. We'll be gald to help.

Comment: Have you tried to use https://www.mathcha.io/editor ?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a start. Make sure you have a look at https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf, especially the document [`Minimal introduction to TikZ (unofficial)`](http://cremeronline.com/LaTeX/minimaltikz.pdf). `pgfplots` might be too much at the beginning if you have never used it. In that case, just use `tikz` in the beginning.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis x line=bottom,
    axis y line=left,
    xmin=0, 
    xmax=10,
    ymin=0, 
    ymax=10,
]
\draw[blue, line width = 1pt, ->] (axis cs:1,2) -- (axis cs:5,6);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's another start that is taken out straight of the manual for `tikz/pgf`.

```
\documentclass{article} % say
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
We are working on
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (-1.5,0) -- (1.5,0);
\draw (0,-1.5) -- (0,1.5);
\end{tikzpicture}.
\end{document}
```

[image]